# What does this code do? im trying to learn some for loop with modulo

Tags: javascript, for-loop

**this is only a part of the code**

What does this loop do? This is a JavaScript for loop I'm trying to learn some JavaScript with modulo in it but I can't understand this one.

```js
for (var x = 2; x < n; x++) {
  if (n % x === 0) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like a really inefficient prime number check. As soon as it finds a number that n is divisible by, it exits false. If it can't find one, it exits true.

Comment: Which part of the code is not clear? `n%x === 0` check?

Answer (score 0):

The above code will increment x (starting at 2) until it's 1 less than n. Each iteration, it checks if "n" can be evenly divided by "x". (Modulos are used to find the remainder). If it is evenly divisible, the program return false.

This code is a prime number checker. If it gets to the bottom it means "n" can only be divided by itself and returns true.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).